# Load ES6 module A if available, fall back to module B if not available

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, requirejs, es6-modules

I'm currently working on a JavaScript library where we would like to migrate legacy [AMD modules](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) to [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

The sample code for this library uses an [AMD plugin](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/LoaderPlugins.md) that looks like this :

```
define([
  "require",
  "../../common/ModuleLoad"
], function(require,
            ModuleLoad) {
  /**
   * Dynamically load the info panel.
   * The actual implementation depends on whether the military symbology package is present.
   */
  return {
    load: function(name, parentRequire, onload, config) {
      ModuleLoad.loadConditional(
          "./SpotReportInfoPanelMilSym",
          "./SpotReportInfoPanelFallback",
          require,
          onload,
          config,
          ["MilSymMissing", "Military Symbology has not been installed.<br />This sample has additional features if Military Symbology is installed."]
      );
    }
  };
});
```

This plugin has the following module as a dependency :

```
define([
  "./toast",
  "./request"
], function(toast,
            request) {

  return {
    loadConditional: function(preferred, fallback, parentRequire, onload, config, message) {
      if (config && config.isBuild) {
        onload();
      } else {
        //do ajax call to check for presence of module.
        return request(parentRequire.toUrl(preferred + ".js")).then(function() {
          //the module exists -> load it using the AMD module loader
          parentRequire([preferred], function(module) {
            onload(module);
          })
        }).catch(function(err) {
          //the module is not present -> return fallback
          if(message) {
            toast.error(message[0], message[1], err);
          }
          parentRequire([fallback], function(module) {
            onload(module);
          })
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Basically, what this code does, is check for the existence of a file named `SpotReportInfoPanelMilSym.js` and return its content as an AMD module. If `SpotReportInfoPanelMilSym.js` is not found, it falls back to `SpotReportInfoPanelFallback.js`.

The reason for this, is that `SpotReportInfoPanelMilSym.js` is only shipped with an optional add-on for this library, whereas `SpotReportInfoPanelFallback.js` is always available. And the sample is supposed to automatically pick the right `SpotReportInfoPanel` implementation depending on the availability of this add-on.

Is there a way to achieve this same behavior with ES6 modules?

We're planning to ship our sample code with Webpack, so a Webpack based solution would be acceptable. However, I would prefer our sample code to work with any loader or bundler and thus would like to avoid and Webpack-specific stuff in our sample code if possible at all.

Comment: This is nothing that ES6 module syntax provides out of the box (just like AMD doesn't), but you can probably write a plugin for the module loader/bundler that you are using to achieve the same. Is it webpack, as suggested by your tag?

Comment: @Bergi : Plugins actually are [a part of the "official" AMD spec](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/LoaderPlugins.md). And we had no trouble replacing the Dojo loader with RequireJS in the past, without having to change the syntax. ——— Anyway, our library is supposed to be compatible with Webpack, Rollup, SystemJS... or any other loader / bundler... or just natively runnable in the browser. Since this is "just" sample code and most of our customers use Webpack, I guess a Webpack plugin is acceptable, but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: You could compile ES6 modules to AMD and just continue to use the same plugin :-) I guess using SystemJS as a loader has an option to configure fallbacks for specific modules, but afaik native browser module implementations don't support any of this. For them, you'll have to do away with dynamic import, and live with the export being a promise (until top-level `await` is a thing).

Comment: @Bergi : Currently all of our code is written and shipped as ECMAScript 5 AMD modules + handcoded TypeScript defs. Since most of our customers are using Webpack and often TypeScript, we want to migrate all of our source code to TypeScript, and ship them as ECMAScript 6 modules + auto-generated TypeScript defs for our 2020 release, with sample code served with Webpack. ——— Either way, we want to avoid our customers having to use AMD anymore. The library source code should be 100% loader / bundler independent. And the sample code should change as little as possible.

Comment: I guess in that case, [dynamic `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports) will be your best bet.